# Why is there a sticker with a question mark attached to this print-out?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-night

At the end of *Game Night* (2018) we see a detailed look at how Gary planned to hijack Brooks's game night. There is a sticker with a question mark attached to the print-out of Donald Anderton's criminal record.

[image]

Why is there a sticker with a question mark attached to this print-out?

Comment: Because he's not sure about Danny's report or about Danny?

Comment: Because he wants to know why or how Donald has never been convicted of any crime he was charged with.